# A way to center an SVG or raster graphic with the same code?

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

For whatever reason, I can't seem to get Firefox to render SVGs through CreateJS. Probably a bug, but I'm willing to fallback to raster graphics. The problem is I can't position a raster graphic vs an SVG the same way using the same code. What I mean is, the code to center an SVG in my canvas is not the same as the code to center a raster graphic. I'm not sure if this is intentional or not.

For the following code snippets, `width` and `height` are the width and height of the canvas element.

This works for raster graphics, but not SVGs:

```
  let bounds = bitmap.getBounds();
  bitmap.regX = bounds.width / 2;
  bitmap.regY = bounds.height / 2;
  bitmap.x = width / 2;
  bitmap.y = height / 2;
  stage.update();
```

This works for SVGs, but not raster graphics (would need to be modified if the SVG isn't square):

```
  bitmap.regX = Math.min(width,height) / 2;
  bitmap.regY = Math.min(width,height) / 2;
  bitmap.x = width / 2;
  bitmap.y = height / 2;
  stage.update();
```

Here's an example on CodePen: https://codepen.io/CorySanin/pen/joOxMZ

Is there a simpler way to center these elements?

Comment: That answers the X of your X-Y problem, if you still want the Y, then let me know so I can reopen.

Comment: Actually, I think knowing the answer to X should help me solve Y. Sounds to me like simply specifying a width and height for the SVG will not only allow it to display in Firefox, but I expect that will make positioning it work the same way as raster graphics. If that's not the case, I'll ping you to reopen. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue here is not CreateJS, but SVG images in Firefox.

If you breakpoint the first scale function `method1` and inspect the image that is loaded, it has no width or height (they are 0).

Here is a modified codepen that shows the image width (and natural width): https://codepen.io/lannymcnie/pen/GagpgP?editors=0010

EaselJS relies on image bounds to determine its own size, and it appears like Firefox has trouble with *some* SVG images. There may be a way to solve it by [ensuring the viewbox has sizes specified](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=614649#c44) on the root element, but I didn't look into it too deeply.

Because the bounds is null, an error is thrown in your code, and it exits the centering function.